# PHP: Proceedural code - use namespace or array of closures to avoid polluting global namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces, closures, procedural

I am just starting to write a piece of open source software that is written procedurally as an alternative to OOP mvc skeletons/frameworks.  So, while I could just write my own OOP MVC framework, the intended purpose is to do it all procedurally.  This is for learning purposes and for purposes of having a DIY codebase ready for when doing a new project.  I'm not fully versed on OOP yet, so I feel like doing it this way is a step in that direction.  However, the purpose of this project is to be a procedural alternative so it must be written procedurally (and I'm giving this preface to avoid answers of using OOP).

After starting writing I'm realizing that the code is polluting the global namespace a lot (like procedural code is wont to do).

At first, to solve the problem of polluting the global namespace and minimizing accidental naming conflicts, I decided to prefix the variables and functions used like so:

`$prefix_variableName = 'value';`
`prefix_functionName($var){ return $var; }`

Then I realized there are better ways to do this.  I have two ideas:

1: Create a global array of closures.  This way the only global I've set in the code is the single array.. like so..

```
$myApp = array(
    'var1' => 'value1',
    'var2' => 'value2',
    'function1' => function($var1){ return $var1; },
    'function2' => function($var2){ return $var2; }
//etc
);
```

2: Create a namespace for the global code at the top of every file.. like..

```
namespace myApp;

$var1 = 'value1';
function1($msg){ return $msg; }
```

Are both of these options are possible?  Can procedural code be namespaced? Which one of these is the better option for this circumstance, and why?  Are there any more options?

Comment: "I want to write a non-OO project" [proceeds to reinvent PHP OO] The problems that you're having are *the exact reason for OO*.

Comment: I created a function called getResource once. It accepted a key (string) , declared a static array, and returned false if the key was not in the array.

Comment: @sammitch, you are correct.  however, I can still write procedural code and try to avoid the problems if I can, right?  The code is going to be non-OO while maximizing avoiding the problems.  It's a hurdle for sure but it's needed for the intended purpose.  My project is going to be for people who either want to write procedural, or do not know OO (and I wish something like this would've been available to me).

Comment: Actually, @sammitch, you are right. If I want to write a procedural project, I have to accept the problems that come with it. I think I'll stick with prefixes because that is the best solution. If I namespace, that makes things way more difficult with a bunch of typing long function names and looking up namespace names (e.g \MyApp\Db\Mysql\Query()) and really just urges OOP practices in a weird procedural setting.  If I use an array of closures I'd only have 1 global variable, but then every single variable and function MyApp uses would be available on every page.   I'll stick to prefixes.

Comment: @Scott I have to disagree to ruling out namespaces just because of "bunch of typing". I think the names add clarity to the code and if you are using an editor with name suggestions/completion you should be.

Comment: @bassxzero If my target audience is procedural programmers (and let's face it, not many people who know OOP are going to program proceedurally because they just *want to*), many of them may never have even seen the namespace syntax, let alone type \MyApp\Db\Mysql\Query() every time they need a db query.  It just seems that for my target demographic, prefixes fix more problems than they solve.. even if they aren't the most elegant solution.  What's your reasoning for disagreeing?  Because it's what *should* be done?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can use namespaces for procedural code. Check the docs to see how it works: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

You should always namespace your code to prevent collision. Using an array of closures might produce unwanted behavior like giving the user the ability to unset the value in the global array and the code expecting the callable errors.

Comment: Thank you.  Namespacing sounds like a good idea, except.... (thought continues).  I think I need to separate what I'm doing here.  The project setup and internal code could be namespaced.  But for things that people need to use.. like for example namespace \MyApp\Db\Mysql would be hard to type every time they need the function \MyApp\Db\Mysql\Query();  That's a lot to type.  Perhaps the internal dealings/setup could be namespaced and stuff that is to be used by the end user could not be.  Idk, I have to think.  I think idk how I want to design this.  I'm sorry for the premature question.

Comment: I figured it out.  Since I'm forcing this project to be procedural, I'll have to accept the shortcomings that it has.  If I namespace, the user would have to type too much for every function call (like I said, e.g. \MyApp\Db\Mysql\Query()).  If I use an array of closures, it could end up being a huge array, with some vars/functions available or not depending on if the file was included (like db vars/functions wouldn't be there if I didn't include the db file).  Also, weird syntax for procedural coders ($myApp['db']['query']($params)).  I'll stick with prefixes (just MyApp_Db_Query($params)).